# "ruby -I lib test/test_person.rb" not loading "lib"

Tags: ruby, include, require

just learning ruby.

I have two folders inside my directory:
"lib" and "test"

Inside lib\person.rb:

```
class Person
 attr_accessor :name
  def introduction
   "Hello, my name is #{name}!"
  end
end
```

Inside test\test_person.rb:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'person'
 class TestPerson < Minitest::Test
  def test_introduction
   person = Person.new
   person.name = 'Bob'
   assert(person.introduction == 'Hello, my name is Bob!')
  end
 end
```

When I try to run: ruby -I lib test/test_person.rb I get the following error:

```
 (...) cannot load such file -- person (LoadError) (...)
```

The -I argument seems that is not working. I get the same error without it.
Any clue?
Tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just figure out what is going on...

I am Brazilian, and we have special characters for accents.
My folder name had one of this "ê".
Ruby is able to load the lib. But not able to recall it.

```
D:\OneDrive\Documentos\Documentos Felipe\Assuntos Acadêmicos>irb -I lib
irb(main):001:0> $:
```

=> ["D:/OneDrive/Documentos/Documentos Felipe/Assuntos Acad\x88micos/lib",(...)

\x88 = ê

Changed the folder name. Now it is ok.
If anyone knows how to solve this without worry about the name, would be helpful.

Tnks!